# dailymotion api mobile website issues

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am trying to play embed videos in my webpage, in desktop browser there is no problem, but in mobile version I have these issues:

- Video wont start automaticaly
- There is Dailymotion logo in right bottom corner

I am using DM object provided by file https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js.

Code:

```
<script src="https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>
<script>
    DM.init({
        apiKey: 'correct api key',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     });
</script>
<div id="player{$img->getId()}" class="dailymotion tile"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var player{$img->getId()} = DM.player(document.getElementById("player{$img->getId()}"), {
            {var DMurl = explode("/", $img->getImgUrl())}
            video: {$DMurl[count($DMurl) - 1]},
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            params: {
                autoplay: true,
                mute: true,
                endscreen-enable: false,
                ui-logo: true,
                controls: false
            }
         });
         player{$img->getId()}.play();
    });
</script>
```

My problem might be caused by syntax error in params (endscreen-enable and ui-logo, phpstorm is showing syntax error because of '-' char)

Answer (score 0):

- Video wont start automatically
  => this is normal on mobile devices, it will be the same for any video you add, from any provider. The reason is that most mobile devices prevent videos from being played automatically, hence the play must be triggered by a user interaction. This is detailed on Dailymotion developer website at : https://developer.dailymotion.com/player/faq#player-faq-autoplay-does-not-work-on-mobile
- There is Dailymotion logo in right bottom corner
  => you pass `ui-logo: true` so this is normal !